# VC++ __stdcall callbacks in C#

Tags: c#, c++, callback, dllimport

I am working on a C# gui application that needs to call into a C++ dll. It appears that all calls are working except one in particular. From the C++ header file the function and callback signature are such:

```
typedef void (__stdcall *LPFNDLL_RECEIVE_CALLBACK)(CANMsg*);

USBCANPLUS_API
CAN_STATUS __stdcall canplus_setReceiveCallBack(
    CANHANDLE handle,
    LPFNDLL_RECEIVE_CALLBACK cbfn
);
```

Based on readings I have setup and inner class wrapping the call as such:

```
[DllImport("USBCanPlusDllF.dll")]
public static extern int canplus_setReceiveCallBack(int handle, CallbackDelegate callback);

[UnmanagedFunctionPointerAttribute(CallingConvention.StdCall)]
public delegate void CallbackDelegate(ref CANMsg msg);
```

And used as:

```
    private static void callback(ref EASYSYNC.CANMsg msg)
    {
        Debug.Print(msg.id + ":" + msg.timestamp + ":" + msg.flags + ":" + msg.len + ":" + msg.data);
    }

    static EASYSYNC.CallbackDelegate del = new EASYSYNC.CallbackDelegate(callback);

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int handle = EASYSYNC.canplus_Open(IntPtr.Zero, "1000", IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero, 0);

        if(handle > 0)
        {
            int result = EASYSYNC.canplus_setReceiveCallBack(handle, del);
        }
    }
```

I know dealing with C++ callbacks in C# are tricky and have read up a bit on the subject, hence I have the code above. My problem is one my code hits the int result = .... line the whole program goes out to lunch indicating that I am probably still doing something wrong with handling the callback. Can anyone advise?

Comment: Is this a typo? I'd expect to see `(handle, del)` instead of `(handle, callback)` at the end of the `int result = ` line.

Comment: *Never* use a message box in a callback, use Debug.Print() instead.  Your code will also bomb when the garbage collector destroys the delegate, you'll need to save it in a static variable.

Comment: Indeed a typo. I will correct in the original post.

Comment: @HansPassant corrections made as per your comment. Same issue. Also, I am certain the callback is not firing as of yet so the issue is isolated to setting the callback.

Comment: Your vague figurative statement suggests that the program does not ever return from the int `result =` line. Is that the case? This seems to be the "correct" way according to MSDN to pass a function pointer in C# (also, stdcall is considered the default calling convention for any new delegate type). I assume `CANHANDLE` actually is a compatible 4 byte type, but are you building the C# *project* (not *solution*) as x86? If it's x64 or Any CPU, the delegate is passed as a 64 bit pointer and corrupts the stack.

Comment: @Dialer. Yes the code never returns from canplus_setReceiveCallback(). From the C++ `typedef long CANHANDLE;` and long is supposed to be a 32bit type. I am building in 32 bit mode. As the default on my machine is 64 bit I got a "wrong format" error prior to going to x86.

Comment: If you still have no idea (and got some spare time), I'd suggest you check whether the marshalling is actually the problem by writing your own C wrapper dll. The dll implements a proper compatible callback (which pops a MessageBox() or sth.), and one "factory-like" function that returns the address of the callback. In C#, call the "factory" (have it return IntPtr), and, also in C#, pass that IntPtr return value as the callback argument instead of `del`. Marshalling an IntPtr should definitely work as expected. If it still doesn't work by then, I'd say the marshalling isn't the problem.

Comment: @Dialer Thanks. I will try that on monday.

Comment: The GC moves delegate objects around, have you tried using a GCHandle to ensure that the delegate object does not move around?

Comment: Have you tried using MDA? Check this post [MDA: Callback On Garbage Collected Delegate](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/sasha/archive/2010/06/11/mda-callback-on-garbage-collected-delegate.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I am a little unsure about this but you have specified the calling convention on the delegate to be StdCall (which it must be because the C/C++ code says so) but you did not do it for the canplus_setReceiveCallBack() dllimport function declaration, does it work when you do the following:

```
[DllImport("USBCanPlusDllF.dll", CallingConvention=CallingConvention.StdCall)]
public static extern int canplus_setReceiveCallBack(int handle, CallbackDelegate callback);
```

As I said, I am unsure but this might be the problem.